# Types of parameters are incompatible - string and array of strings

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a component which accepts `onChange` function (property).

Its definition is following:

```
onChange: (str: string | string[]) => void;
```

So, it means: `str` is either a `string` OR an array of `string`. When I use my component, I have a function which will be accepting only single string (`setNoOfCols` is a function from `useState` hook -> ):

```
const [noOfCols, setNoOfCols] = useState<string>('basic');
...
onChange: (value: string): void => setNoOfCols(value)
```

Unfortunately, I receive an error from Typescript saying that

```
TS2322: Type '(value: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(str: string | string[]) => void'.
Types of parameters 'value' and 'str' are incompatible.
Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

How can I define a function for my component which will use only single string?

Comment: You can just cast it to string ```onChange: (value: any) => setNoOfCols(value as string)```. But you should deal with the issue, you should check if the value is a string or an array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid this error by using the correct signature while using `useState` like below

```
const [noOfCols, setNoOfCols] = useState<string|string[]>('basic');
```

Or you can update your `onChange` type definition like this :

```
type onChange = ((str: string|string[]) => void) | ((str: string[]) => void);
```